# In Firefox SWF content in Jquery tabs component doesn't load/unload like in Chrome and Safari. How can i fix this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, flash

I'm working a tab mechanic using jquery... the mechanic of showing and hiding content isn't a problem. But how SWFs behave in the tabs... in Firefox is.
In Chrome and Safari it works perfectly. If you click on a tab - you see the swf appear, and it plays from the start. If you click another tab, and then go back to the previous tab the flash content re-loads/starts again.

However my problem is with Firefox, It doesn't work the same... you click on a tab - you see the swf appear, but it had already started - presumably as the page loaded. If you click another tab, and then go back to the previous tab the flash content has carried on.

How do I make swf content in any tab start/re-load when the tab is clicked, and unload when you click a different tab.

My code is the standard jquery tab code...

```
    <div id="tabs" class="flashes">
        <h3>Online Advertising</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><img src="thumb1.jpg"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="thumb2.jpg"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="thumb3.jpg"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
        <p>content in a tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
      <div class="mpu"> 
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
width="300" height="250" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,40,0"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="src" value="300x250.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="250" 
src="300x250.swf" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
</embed>
</object>
    </div> </div>
    <div id="fragment-3">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
sed diam nonummy nibh   euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore 
magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Only extra code I have is to not have any tabs open on page load

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        selected: -1
    });

    }); 
    </script>
```

Be great if anyone could share how to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true,
        selected: -1,
        select: function(evt,ui){
           var flashObj = $(ui.panel).find("object");
           if(flashObj.length > 0) {
              $(ui.panel).find("object").remove();
              $(ui.panel).append(flashObj);
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: doh! meant to add more to that comment than just thanks :) ... Sadly it hasn't fixed it. Unless I've implemented it wrong. Can I still use the standard SWF embedding code for that to work?